# Should we have a field for specifying your vehicle when asking a question

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

In the short time its been since I've joined this site its been great!

One thing I've noticed is that there are a lot of questions where the user neglects to specify their vehicle, wherein another user must ask them the make/model/year of their vehicle before they can begin to give an answer/diagnose the problem.

If there was a field to specify your vehicle (somewhere next to the title), I think it would leave a lot of that back and forth out.

It probably shouldn't be mandatory, but I predict that it will increase the accuracy and response times of answers on this site.

Forgive me if this is outside of the realm of suggestions that can be implemented.

Comment: I just wanted to say we appreciate you being here. I'm also glad you are enjoying the site. Your questions thus far have been very good! I hope you ask some more so we can provide some more answers for you. As for this question, this is the *exact* place to ask such a question. As Larry (Move more...) says below, I think the best which could be expected is putting it in the help section. In the mean time, again, it's awesome you're with us!

Comment: Thanks man, looking forward to getting more answers!

Answer (score 6):

We could put in the ["How to ask"](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the site, not that new users read that.

Comment: The latter half of that statement seems absolutely *on target*.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea in my opinion, but I suspect not possible, as I'd imagine the question form is common to all Stack Exchange sites - unless anyone knows differently?

Answer (score 1):

Not all questions are specific to any one vehicle.  There are many questions that are relevant to vehicles generally.  Here is a couple of  [recent](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/5043/stubborn-oil-drain-plug-caused-by-hot-oil) [examples](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/is-it-possible-to-harm-your-car-by-giving-someone-a-boost).

It would be inappropriate to make a vehicle field a mandatory part of the question asking process.  Unless, of course, you have the option to enter "*Not applicable*" or similar.

Comment: fuel injection problems usually have fairly vehicle-agnostic answers